# Adding click event to generated MenuItems with datatemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, click, code-behind

I'm creating a menu dynamically based on a list of "BODPresentationRule" objects. While I can add them to the list, I can't find out how to add a click event to the (sub)MenuItems using the datatemplate.

When I use the PolygonShapesMenu_OnClick Click event from the First MenuItem I can see that there was a click, but not which subMenuItem it was.

XAML:

```
<Menu VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <MenuItem Name="PolygonShapesMenu" Click="PolygonShapesMenu_OnClick">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Assets/Images/polygon.png" Height="24" Width="24"></Image>
                <Label>Polygoon</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The code behind (creating the menu)
*[note, due to the nature of the app, I'm not using MVVM (lots of drawing etc...]*:

```
// create and set the datatemplate
DataTemplate polyDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof (BODPresentationRule));
PolygonShapesMenu.ItemTemplate = polyDataTemplate;

// create and add the text box to the data template
var txtElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
polyDataTemplate.VisualTree = txtElement;

// set the binding in the text box bound to the name of the BodPresentationRule
txtElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));

// TODO: how to intercept click event to the current selected item?

// add items to menu
foreach (BODPresentationRule rule in _presentationRules.OrderBy(r=>r.Name))
{
    PolygonShapesMenu.Items.Add(rule);
}
```

FYI, it results in this:

[image: example of menu]

I was thinking about using Triggers to intercept a click event that would be added to the datatemplate, but I'm not even sure if that's the correct way to do it.

Summary: I need to know what BODPresentationRule (MenuItem) was clicked; how can I intercept the correct click event pointing to that rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only handling the click on the "header" MenuItem here. Put the click handler into a Style inside the MenuItem's ItemContainerStyle.

```
<MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="PolygonShapesMenu_OnClick"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

The clicked sub MenuItem will then be the sender.

Comment: Ha, didn't think of using a style with TargetType. Thanks! It works (FYI, second line should ne of course <MenuItem.Resources>). Happy holidays!